# Do monsters give back all money they steal?

Tags: terraria

If an enemy picks up 5 gold in expert mode, will it give back 5 gold or some fraction of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will drop the entire amount collected (75% of your total gets dropped in expert mode), however it's extremely hard to find the same enemy again as it will probably despawn, unless it was very close to your player spawn. If it indeed despawns, the coins are lost forever.

The enemy holding your coins will be the one with a sparkly effect.

Comment: If you meant that 75% gets dropped on player death, you might want to specify that, as it looks like you mean monsters drop 100% of their stolen money in normal, but only 75% in expert.